# Monodevelop error Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to compiling in monodevelop, but I'm getting this error: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.

But when I run it in the Terminal it works with no problem.  So I guess it's a problem with monodevelop, but what is the problem?

There's no error,because I can run it fine using the terminal, the message error in monodevelop is:

> Digite um numero:  Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: s   at System.Int32.Parse
>   (System.String s) [0x00012] in
>   /build/buildd/mono-3-opt-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs:630
>   at programa02.Main () [0x00000] in :0  [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: s   at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s)
>   [0x00012] in
>   /build/buildd/mono-3-opt-3.2.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs:630
>   at programa02.Main () [0x00000] in :0  The
>   application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP

```
class programa02
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int num1, num2, soma;
        System.Console.Write("Digite um numero: ");
        num1=int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        System.Console.Write("Digite outro numero: ");
        num2=int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        soma = num1+num2;
        System.Console.Write(soma);
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    } 
}
```

Comment: wheres the error message occuring? at which line? Possibly the libraries aren't linked to perform System.Console operations

Comment: Your application rely on having a Console to read numbers. That's why it fails if there's no console. Are you sure your project has been created has a "Console Project" ?

Comment: I did what you said, but now I'm getting: Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Type 'System.Collections.Concurrent.IProducerConsumerCollection`1' not found in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'